# Error connecting to databasehandler

Tags: sqlite

I have a error regarding database as shown below:
E/CursorWindow(386): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 63

here's my piece of code:

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Methods contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE,contact.getImageId());
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Methods getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,KEY_IMAGE,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Methods contact = new Methods(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))),
            cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMAGE)),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PH_NO)));
    // return contact
    cursor.close();
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Methods> getAllContacts() {
    List<Methods> contactList = new ArrayList<Methods>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery =  "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Methods contact = new Methods();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setImageId(cursor.getBlob(1));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(3));

            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}   

/*// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Methods contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}*/

// Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Methods contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
        Log.v("deleteContact", "Deleted row is:  "+String.valueOf(contact.getID()));
    }   

void deleteAll(Methods contact)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null);
    db.close();

}
// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you in advance if anybody helps........

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have more information here (a stack trace perhaps?). However it seems you're not providing an "id" when adding a contact. Consider making this column auto incrementing instead.

Last, if this is an Android question, your primary key column should be auto incrementing and should be called "_id", else make sure that this is given as a column name in any cursor returned from a query. Also check that your database has a table called "android_metadata" too.

Comment: can you write a query of adding contact as needed in my example, and isn't i want to change the name of id as _id in my database??

Comment: @user1478187 If you haven't already done so, and again assuming this is actually an Android question (we are discussing the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class here so it is plausible), like the rest of us you need to read up on the basics of developing for Android first before asking.

Comment: yes i know the basics of android but just want to get the query what other advice to solve my above problem......so if any one helps its nice!